# PySpark UDF does not return expected result

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a Databricks dataframe with multiple columns and a UDF that generates the contents of a new column, based on values from other columns.

A sample of the original dataset is:

```
interval_group_id     control_value     pulse_value     device_timestamp

2797895314            5                 5               2020-09-12 09:08:44
0                     5                 5               2020-09-12 09:08:45
0                     6                 5               2020-09-12 09:08:46
0                     0                 5               2020-09-12 09:08:47
```

Now I am trying to add a new column, called `group_id`, based on some logic with the columns above. My UDF code is:

```
@udf('integer')
def udf_calculate_group_id_new (interval_group_id, prev_interval_group_id, control_val, pulse_val):
  
  if interval_group_id != 0:
    return interval_group_id
  elif control_val >= pulse_val and prev_interval_group_id != 0:
    return prev_interval_group_id
  else:
    return -1
```

And the new column being added to my dataframe is done with:

```
df = df.withColumn('group_id'
                   , udf_calculate_group_id_new(
                          df.interval_group_id                                                   
                          , lag(col('interval_group_id')).over(Window.orderBy('device_timestamp'))            
                          , df.control_value
                          , df.pulse_value)
                  )
```

---

My expected results are:

```
interval_group_id    control_value    pulse_value   device_timestamp       group_id

2797895314           5                5             2020-09-12 09:08:44    2797895314
0                    5                5             2020-09-12 09:08:45    2797895314
0                    6                5             2020-09-12 09:08:46    2797895314
0                    0                5             2020-09-12 09:08:47    -1
```

However, the results of adding the new `group_id` column are:

```
interval_group_id    control_value    pulse_value   device_timestamp       group_id

2797895314           5                5             2020-09-12 09:08:44    null
0                    5                5             2020-09-12 09:08:45    null
0                    6                5             2020-09-12 09:08:46    -1
0                    0                5             2020-09-12 09:08:47    -1
```

My **goal** is to propagate the value `2797895314` down the `group_id` column, based on the conditions mentioned above, but somehow this doesn't happen and the results are populated with `null` and `-1` incorrectly.

Is this a bug with UDF's or is my expectation of the way of working for the UDF incorrect? Or am I just bad at coding?

Comment: Looking at the udf code, I think in your example data the column `device_timestamp` is missing. Also the column `interval_group_id` should probably be named `interval_group_id_start`?

Comment: @werner are the names of the columns used and parameters of the UDF supposed to match?

Comment: no, not the parameter names of the udf function. But the column names that are used when calling the udf within the the `withColumn` call should be present in the dataframe

Comment: @werner oh, my bad .. it was a typo in my question, I had to rename some the columns from NDA's sake and I couldn't decide on a column re-name :) I'll fix it, just so they match. Also, the `device_timestamp` should be self-explanatory, but I added it with sample data so that the logic is clear.

Comment: Two things: 1.) Could you try to replace `@udf('integer')` with `@udf('long')`? 2.) The two `-1` that you see are correct in my opinion: you check for `prev_interval_group_id != 0` and this condition is false for row 3 and 4 and thus the result is -1.